# How to continue touches/gesture to next view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am interested in developing a Snapchat like gesture in my project, where a touch event will invoke a new view controller and only when user's finger is still down, the view controller is visible.

Currently, I managed to implement a `wildcard gesture recognizer` that contain callback blocks for `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded`.

```
var touchesBeganCallback : ((NSSet, UIEvent)-> Void)?
var touchesMovedCallback : ((NSSet, UIEvent)-> Void)?
var touchesEndedCallback : ((NSSet, UIEvent)-> Void)?
```

I added a `wildcard gesture recognizer` to second view controller before it is shown through a segue:

```
destVC.view.addGestureRecognizer(drawWildGestureRecognizer({ (touches:NSSet, event:UIEvent) -> Void in
    println("LDetailViewController: touches began")
    }, touchesEndedCallback: { (touches:NSSet, event:UIEvent) -> Void in
       println("LDetailViewController: touches ended")
    }))
```

Of course, my first view controller already has `wildcard gesture recognizer` added. But the touches seem not to continue to my second view controller, even though if I tap on my second view controller's view again and gesture recognizer is recognizing the touches correctly.

What else should I do here?

Comment: Do you know that Snapchat's touch down invokes a new view controller, as opposed to just a new view?

Comment: That is what I guessed, so my question is about continuing the touches to a view controller

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can take the touches `NSSet` and `UIEvent` and pass them via properties to the new controller, but that's probably not necessary as whenever the user moves their finger then the OS will send new touch events.

I believe whatever controller is in the window then it's view should pick up the new events. Therefore, you can pass a "didPress" bool value to the new controller, and then listen for the `touchesEnded` delegate to be called on the new controller. That should give you the interaction you desire.

Keep in mind this is off cuff so you may need the play around with it a bit.

Comment: It won't provoke touchesEnded without provoking touchesBegan first or manually forcing it to start

Comment: Hmm, how are you adding the new view controller? Are you adding it to the navigation stack, or are you adding it as a child view controller? Have you tried to use child view controllers?

Comment: I had to use child view controller to achieve just that

Answer (score 0):

My solution has three steps:

1. Instantiate your child view controller from storyboard, do note that you will set `storyboardID` for the view controller in order to instantiate.

   ```
   postDetailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("showPost") as? LDetailViewController
   if postDetailViewController != nil {
     //add child view
     let postDetailView = postDetailViewController!.view
     self.view.addSubview(postDetailView)

     //add child view controller
     self.addChildViewController(postDetailViewController!)
     postDetailViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
   } else {
     fatalError("postDetailViewController fails to be created")
   }
   ```
2. Implement a wildcard gesture recognizer, which executes a `touchesBeganBlock` when touches began, to a `table view cell` or any other object you want to attach this gesture to in your **parent view controller**, like the following:

   ```
   var touchesBeganCallback : ((NSSet, UIEvent)-> Void)?
   func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
     if (touchesBeganCallback != nil){
       touchesBeganCallback!(touches,event)
     }
   }
   ```

   This `touchesBeganBlock` will call a function that instantiate the view controller(code in step 1)
3. At last, when touches ended, executes a `touchesEndBlock` which simply calls a function to discard your child view controller:

   ```
   var touchesEndedCallback : ((NSSet, UIEvent)-> Void)?
   func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
     if (touchesEndedCallback != nil){
       touchesEndedCallback!(touches,event)
     }
   }
   ```

   on mine, the block executes the following code:

   ```
   if (postDetailViewController != nil){
     postDetailViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
     postDetailViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
     postDetailViewController = nil
   }
   ```

Comment: Is there a reason you'e using a gesture recognizer and these callbacks, as opposed to just implementing touchesBegan and touchesEnded in the first controller's self.view? This solution doesn't continue the touches to the next view controller though does it? Do you just have the one gesture recognizer that's on the first view?

Comment: I think I was not quite clear about where to put the gesture recognizer, it should be put in parent view controller. The reason to use a custom gesture recognizer class is to make code cleaner. You can simply call `touchesBegan` in your parent view controller. Doesnt make any difference, as long as you use child view controller.

Comment: Also, `touchesBegan` in view controller intercepts all touches occurred in a view controller. This will result in writing a bunch of if statements to switch between different code. Anyway, its just a matter of readability imo.